# Highcharts - How to get default y-Axis label formatter in a custom formatter

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I hope to write a custom label formatter, which will show custom label in some conditions and return the default one in other conditions:

```
function yAxisFormatter() {
    var val = //need default formatter value here 
    if(someCondition){
       val = ....
    }

    return val;
}
```

[Doc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter) says the default formatter is

```
function() {
    return this.value;
}
```

But `this.value` shows differently from the default one, I need the default label like 9k rather than 9000 and so on.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone else stumbles upon this (like I have) you don't need to copy part of the core. The default formatter is defined as part of the axis object. You can fallback like so:

```
function myCustomFormatter() {
       var result = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
       //Do your own things here.
       return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract part of code from core and then you achieve that.

```
formatter: function () {
                var numericSymbolDetector = this.axis.isLog ? this.value : this.axis.tickInterval,
                    numericSymbols = this.chart.options.lang.numericSymbols,
                    i = numericSymbols && numericSymbols.length,
                    value = this.value,
                    ret=value, 
                    multi;

                if (i && numericSymbolDetector >= 1000) {
                    ret = UNDEFINED;
                    while (i-- && ret === UNDEFINED) {
                        multi = Math.pow(1000, i + 1);
                        if (numericSymbolDetector >= multi && numericSymbols[i] !== null) {
                            ret = Highcharts.numberFormat(value / multi, -1) + numericSymbols[i];
                        }
                    }
                }

                return ret;

            }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/x9r35s5q/5/

Comment: There are some problem when a value is less than 1000. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/x9r35s5q/1/, do you miss initializing `ret=value`?

Comment: Correct ;) small mistake

Comment: Well,  please note that I don't know why, the behavior changed after we set ret =value, please check http://jsfiddle.net/x9r35s5q/3/. Also, if we initialize the `ret =value`, then is the condition `&ret === UNDEFINED` still needed, is `this.value` can be undefined?

Comment: You can add line to reset REF value by setting UNDEFINED or removing condition in the while.

Comment: Copy/pasting code is never a very good idea. I strongly suggest to consider apokryfos' answer instead.